# Why Dothraki's hut get burned so fast?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Connected to the episode s06e04. Was there any fuel spilled inside the hut when Daenerys set it on fire?

Comment: Non canon answer here but you could tell that some sort of fluid fuel was what was used in the fires which were spilled, judging by the flow of the fire. However, the hut itself was flammable materials literally dried in a desert and likely already fairly lightweight to allow breezes through.

Comment: The bigger question is: If this was Daenerys' plan, how did she know there would be big oil lamps that would burn bright enough to kill all the khals.

Comment: @TLP this was the same place where she ate the horse heart, and Drogo declared that he would sail with her to take Westeros.  I don't have access to that scene...were there braziers there at that time?

Comment: @Liesmith Would she really remember and base her entire future upon the braziers being that easy to overturn, their content that flammable, and the hut that ... dry and combustible. I can just picture the scene in a different light, where she pushes over a brazier, and it just scatters glowing coal at their feet and the khal says "What are you doing?" -> Anticlimax.

Comment: @TLP: This hut was/is a temple (building) of the dosh khaleen, isn't it. Maybe she asked to have the lamps filled extra full because it would be a long night. Still I think the fire was a little too eager to consume the hut. Even burning the hut is strong enough to keep Khals scared for their lives inside. Maybe it wasn't normal fire to begin with? (Of course I'm just trying to deny more obvious explanations)

Comment: @user1129682 Well, if you are looking for excuses, magic is often useful. How she know the fire would save her? Magic. Fire and Blood.

Comment: @TLP: Dany red priestress confirmed. :-)

Comment: How did she know about the big oil lamps?  Remember the girl she took with her?  If I was Daenerys I'd be pumping her for all the information I could get out of her.

Answer (score 10):

Those braziers she tips over are full of oil... which **is** a fuel. This is why the fire splashes across the floor when the braziers fall over. They're giant, open oil lamps.

As the oil splashes out and hits the wood of the hut, it helps spread the fire quickly because it's designed to burn.

Haven't found any direct confirmation but this [Daily Kos episode recap article](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2016/5/16/1527058/-Game-of-Thrones-6-4-recap-The-Book-of-the-Stranger) has the same interpretation:

> Challenged, insulted, and threatened with both gang rape and horses (how do you get a horse to … never mind) Dany casually grabs the edge of the nearest brazier and tips a few gallons of burning oil toward the khals. She then repeats this maneuver several times, turning the massive tent into a billowing pyre and crisping every Dothraki leader in one neat package. And she does it without even needing a dragon.

To add to this, don't forget that this is likely happening in some form of compressed time (because movies are magic). We see it happen over two and a half minutes but, realistically, it was likely at least 10 minutes if not 15-20 minutes as that gives enough time for everyone from the entire camp to assemble and for the entire building to be consumed.

Comment: Was it oil? I wasn't paying super close attention, but I thought they were braziers full of coals.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was oil... I'll see if I can find a video of it or at least rewatch it... but the fire was very splash-y to be just coal.

Comment: The reddit spoilers thread seems to agree that it was oil... https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/4jj4k6/spoilers_extended_game_of_thrones_season_6/ (search the page for "braziers".

Comment: Here's the scene on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwoYX-uM1AE It's not absolutely definitive, it could just be fire spreading extremely fast, but I agree it looks like there's probably oil. So +1 for you and an edit for me.

Comment: IT had to be oil/melted fat: Dothraki are not miners, brazers were too small and bright for wood. Also coal/wood would smoke too much in a brazier inside a building.

Comment: "gallons". Doesn't look like gallons to me. And the floor is made of stone, too, so most of the oil shouldn't do anything. Oh well ... still a great turn of events.

Comment: @user1129682 Yes, "gallons" is a bit of an overstatement, I agree (but that's a quote, not original content). The braziers don't look like they could hold more than a quart or so of oil.

Comment: Even if the floor had been wood, a flat level surface isn't going to help you get a good fire going quickly.  What doomed them was the fire reached the flammable walls.  Fire loves to crawl up a wall.

Answer (score 3):

Did Danny not imply there was a role for the young widow she was with when she was being 'rescued'? I took it to mean that she was directed to spread something flammable on the ground beforehand...the director went to some lengths to show the fire spreading across a hard surface...j

Answer (score 2):

There probably didn't need to be any fuel spilled in the hut, as the hut was *made* out of fuel.

That being said, the braziers appeared to have some oil in them which spread across the ground quickly once tipped over. Take a bunch of dry wood and grass and apply some burning coals to it. It will light on fire. Take that same wood, pour lighter fluid on it first, and it will ***burst*** into flame.